# Is Hagrid anti-muggle?

Tags: harry-potter, muggles, hagrid

Hagrid shows up to collect Harry, but becomes angry, belligerent, insistent, threatening, and violent as soon as the Dursleys showed reluctance to allow Harry to go.

Is Hagrid giving into anti-muggle sentiment in this situation? Had he viewed them as equals, would he not have been more patient, used calmer language, and engaged in reasoning etc. to allow them a chance to change their minds?

You know, more "let's talk about this like civilized adults" a la Dumbledore or Prof. Xavier, and less "Harry's going, or I'll curse your child".

Comment: He's not anti-Muggle, just anti-jerk. The Dursleys are jerks.

Comment: This is what political correctness gets you.

Comment: Hagrid is both a wizard, and a half-breed magical creature.  He is the very definition of an anti-Muggle.

Comment: @MatthewRock I don't understand. what you mean by "This is what political correctness gets you"?

Comment: It's kind of obvious that Dursleys are jerks, and it isn't a surprise that Hagrid isn't fond of them(after all, not only are they torturing the poor child, but they're making his work harder), yet you thought that being anti-muggle might be the case, without any other indications of this behaviour.

Answer (score 40):

I don't think Hagrid is anti Muggle, he's only belligerent there because of the Dursleys (that is, their behaviour, not them being Muggles). Let's remember that:

- he just tracked them because they wouldn't let Harry read his letter
- he just learnt that Harry did not knew he was a wizard (or that wizard existed, as a matter of fact) and that he has always been told his parents died in a car crash (and, if I recall, Hagrid almost took this as an insult to their memory - sorry, I don't have the book around)
- Vernon Dursley insulted Dumbledore... and well, Hagrid does not really like this.

So yes, he's quite angry! But just because of this specific situation.

(Also, Hagrid is not really a "let's calm down and quietly talk about this" kind of guy.)

Furthemore, we never see him being violent or anything toward any other Muggle, do we? He goes in the muggle Tube, is friend with Hermione (she's not technicaly a Muggle, but anti-muggle people usually don't become friends with muggle borns)...

PS : In my opinion, quietly reasoning with the Dursleys to let them change their minds would not have worked... but that's another question ;)

---

EDIT Just found two dialogs where characters themselves explain the "it's not cause the Dursleys are Muggles, only cause they're awful people" feeling :

> “Why would I want to attack Muggle-borns?”
>   “I’ve heard you hate those Muggles you live with,” said Ernie
>   swiftly.
>   “It’s not possible to live with the Dursleys and not hate them,”
>   said Harry. “I’d like to see you try it.”
>   *(Chamber of secrets, Chapter 11, The Duelling Club)*

and later, about Dudley:

> "We didn't give it to him because he's a Muggle!" said Fred indignantly.
>   "No, we gave it to him because he's a great bullying git," said George. "Isn't he, Harry?"
>   "Yeah, he is, Mr. Weasley," said Harry earnestly.
>   *(Goblet of fire, Chapter 5, Weasleys Wizard Wheezes)*

Comment: Hagrid's exact dialogue is "How could a car crash kill Lily an' James Potter? It's an outrage! A scandal! Harry Potter not knowin' his own story when every kid in our world knows his name!" (From Chapter 4 of PS.) I sense both a little bit of "That's an insult to their memory" and a little bit of "I'm already angry and hearing that ridiculous, absurd statement just made me angrier" from this dialogue.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's more like Mr. Vernon is anti-Wizard.  He's pointed a gun at Hagrid, and you claim that Hagrid was behaving threatening.

Comment: A literal giant of a human being stalks you across the country and busts down your door to take away your adopted child, what would you do?

Comment: @ggmg - Harry seems a surly, sulky, insolent child. They would be well rid of him.

Comment: @Richard That's an interesting observation, Richard. Why were the Dursleys so reluctant to divest themselves of such a recalcitrant child? To the point of barring him in his room at one point?

Comment: Because they hated magic more than they hated Harry. If I'm not mistaken,  this issue has already been discussed in this SE.

Comment: @gandalf - Harry was used as their personal slave.

Comment: @Richard you just made me realize that Harry was treated like a house elf by the Dursleys. Even the part about old Dudley's clothes reminds me of the discarded stuff Dobby was wearing all the time.

Answer (score 3):

**No, Hagrid is not anti-muggle, but he doesn't consider muggles to be equals either.**

His general anger is directed at the Dursley's  specifically for their atrocious behavior, not at muggles in general.  The evidence that he is not anti-muggle is his attitude toward Hermione (from a family of muggles) and his defense of muggle-borns while staying clearly on the side of those who want muggle-borns to continue coming to Hogwarts.  However, that he sees himself and other wizards as superior is shown when he says in the film "Oh and I suppose a great Muggle like yourself is gonna stop him." or in the book "I'd like ter see a great Muggle like you stop him."  His sarcastic disregard of muggle abilities shows a clear contempt for muggle abilities. Now such disregard for muggle abilities doesn't necessarily imply dislike for muggles in general - it may simply be an accurate assessment of muggle abilities compared to those of wizards.  If he hadn't had a sense of superiority over muggles in general he likely would have made it more personal by saying "I'd like ter see you stop him" without referencing Mr. Dursley's muggleness.

Answer (score 2):

**Hagrid isn't anti-muggle, he is angry because of the Dursleys**

When Hagrid becomes angry and threatening to the Dursleys, there are a few reasons. The first reason is that Harry is Hagrid's very good friend, and Hagrid knows that the Dursleys have treated Harry poorly, so, Hagrid will naturally get angry at the Dursleys for treating Harry poorly. The second reason is that the three Dursleys are very anti-wizard. Vernon Dursley hates wizards, and if you have read all of the books or seen all of the movies, you would know that Hagrid respects wizards. I think that the last reason is probably that Hagrid knows all of the terrible lies that the Dursleys have told Harry. Like that his parents died in. car crash, and the magic does not exist. Also, that Vernon Dursley did not let Harry read his letter, and hid his family away in the shed in the middle of the sea. That also leads to having Hagrid chase Harry down so that Harry could come to hogwarts. All these things would have pissed me off a lot.

Comment: "Harry is Hagrid's very good friend" this scene takes place before they're friends. they have literally never spoken before (carrying a young baby for an hour or so doesn't count as bonding or making friends with)

Answer (score 1):

Hagrid is by no stretch of the imagination anti-muggle.  Hagrid, almost more than any other character in the books, believes in equality for all creatures.

He is aware that his presence aggravates the Dursleys and Vernon is openly hostile, and reveals that he lied to Harry about Harry's parents' death.  This was naturally infuriating Hagrid realizing the abuse in this situation.  Withholding that information was meant for control.  Control is a form of abuse (let's hold off on the fact that Harry had been locked in a cupboard for years and was underfed).  Hagrid recognized this and was enraged.

Hagrid is not anti-Muggle.  Hagrid is anti-Dursley.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Hagrid has well defined political views or prejudices. Hagrid follows Dumbledore, so probably shares the views of his beloved headmaster.
His behaviour when he was fetching Harry was because he is no diplomat, so he can be a bit agressive if angered.

But yeah, it's strange that when Vernon vexes him he attacks a 11 year old kid and tries to transfigure him.
Good thing he sucks at doing magic so he doesn't do that much damage. 
He'd probably also atrack Draco if Lucius angered him or something.