# Was Hagrid guilty of blood prejudice?

Tags: harry-potter, hagrid

After Mr Weasley and Mr Malfoy have their fistfight in Flourish and Blotts, Hagrid says:

> "Yeh should've ignored him, Arthur...Rotten ter the core, the whole family, everyone knows that. No Malfoy's worth listenin' ter. **Bad blood**, that's what it is. Come on now - let's get outta here."
>   <sub>*(Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 4, At Flourish and Blotts)*.</sub>

Now I've always understood Hagrid to be saying, in effect, "Don't concern yourself with the Malfoys. They're just a bunch of troublemakers." 'Bad blood' here would refer to the Malfoys' natural proclivity for starting arguments with their taunts and insults. Or he could mean that there *is* bad blood (i.e. [ill-feeling, enmity and hostility](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bad+blood)) between the Malfoys and the Weasleys - and that that's the way it's always going to be.

Then it struck me that he could mean something else. He could be saying that the Malfoys are inherently spiteful, argumentative or disdainful *simply because they are pure-bloods*. In other words, he thinks that the 'blood' of the Malfoys makes them what they are.

Ordinarily, I would dismiss this interpretation as over-thinking Rowling/Hagrid's choice of words, since prejudice of this sort is out of character for Hagrid. However, it's difficult to gloss over Hagrid's statement when you consider the following fact:

**Discrimination based on blood purity is the main central theme of *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*.**

It seems impossible that Rowling or her publisher could have simply slipped this sort of phrase in without thinking about it, considering the subject matter of the book. Purebloods like the Malfoys discriminate against half-bloods and Muggle-borns. The 'good guys' like Dumbledore don't differentiate between people based on their ancestry. So, as I say, Hagrid's language here doesn't fit. Yet are we really to suppose that it was entirely coincidental?

So is there any way of supposing what Hagrid actually meant when he said "bad blood"? Has Rowling commented on this at all?

**Note:** I'm not suggesting that Hagrid was prejudiced against purebloods in general. I'm just asking whether he was in this instance.

Comment: Bad blood is an existing phrase in English as you have discovered yourself. Also remember that Hagrid also states that there isn't a family with pure blood, making your statement saying he thinks they have "bad blood" because of their purity invalid

Comment: @Raditz_35 People like Hagrid still use 'pureblood' as a phrase, even though they know that no family is 100% wizard.

Comment: Your statement is not connected to my comment

Comment: Good find about Hagrid berating the blood of an opposing fraction. There's also plenty of him demeaning muggles, especially in the Philosopher's stone. Also,  [related](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123877/is-hagrid-anti-muggle)

Comment: Hagrid tends to generalise groups (as his famous, "there's hasn't been a single Slytherin who hasn't gone over to the bad side", quote suggests) hero-worship (Dumbledore, James and Lily), but he doesn't discriminate. Had Draco Malfoy been a "blood-traitor", Hagrid is the type of person who would have warmed up to him, as he did with Sirius Black, before he came to be falsely known as a murderer. "Bad blood" here is probably a retaliation to the blood prejudice of the Malfoys. It makes sense that Rowling introduced that phrase, in introduction to the concept of blood prejudice.

Comment: @TheDarkLord: I refer to you as "TheDarkLord" but that doesn't mean I think you're actually [Sauron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Lord_(fiction)), Voldemort, or a Sith Lord. Hagrid can use the word "pureblood" without requiring him to believe that purebloods are in any way superior. If anything, he can even use "pureblood" as a subversion, to mean "those idiots who seem to think that blood purity makes them superior", which creates a different connotation for the usage of "pureblood".

Comment: @AnyaMae You're getting the quote wrong. He didn't say that there hasn't been a single Slytherin that hasn't gone over to the bad side. He said that there hasn't been a single person who has gone over to the bad side that wasn't in Slytherin. In other words, he didn't say that all Slytherins are bad, only that all of the bad people happened to be in Slytherin.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, Right. My bad. But it is still an example of stereotyping, and inducing prejudice in an eleven year old. My point is that he warms up to the so-called "blood-traitors" despite this stereotyping tendency, and his hatred towards blood-prejudiced pure bloods. So it is not a blind prejudice that he has against _all_ pure-bloods.

Comment: It's a reasonably common British phrase amongst the older generation, as covered in answers below. It's fallen somewhat out of use and I'm not aware of it being used in American English, hence where some confusion could arise.

Comment: Hagrid confirmed as a stealth-blood-racist!
Rubeus = red = the colour of blood

Comment: @AnthonyGrist And of course, Quirrell and Lockhart and Pettigrew proved him wrong.

Comment: @JAB Pettigrew is certainly an example of a non-Griffindor going bad, but Lockhart?  He may be stuck up and incompetent, but not evil.  As for Quirrell, we don't know what he was like before Voldemort took up residence in him.  I don't know that I'd consider him having gone evil unless he did so before Voldemort came into the picture.

Comment: @Doc I assume you mean non-Slytherin there. And Hagrid didn't say evil, he said bad. I'd certainly consider Lockhart's usage of Memory charms to steal credit to be unethical at best (possibly illegal if the Ministry has any regulations regarding unauthorized usage on other witches/wizards); you do have a point about Quirrell, however. Checking Pottermore, it was indeed that Quirrell was subjugated by Voldemort rather than ending up serving him of his own will.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

## He does not discriminate.

How many times have we seen him say it doesn't matter? Granted, that's usually in the case of Muggle borns being equal, but...

Consider who he's talking to. He's talking to *the Weasley family*, who are pure bloods (yeah, yeah, I know) themselves. He was a friend of many pure bloods and Muggle borns alike.

Also consider the entire paragraph again:

> Yeh should've ignored him, Arthur...Rotten ter the core, the whole family, everyone knows that. No Malfoy's worth listenin' ter. Bad blood, that's what it is. Come on now - let's get outta here."

The whole paragraph is **demeaning the Malfoy family**. How are families related? Blood. The whole thing is just him decrying the Malfoys. Nothing more.

Comment: _"He does not discriminate. ... The whole thing is just him decrying the Malfoys. Nothing more."_ - So he's decrying people based on which group they belong to, rather than based on their individual actions. Sounds like discrimination to me ;) (just not on blood purity)

Comment: @marcelm - if the group is a family of a bunch of rotten Death Eater supremacists, then yes, you could say he's discriminating by group.

Comment: Could you consider expanding your final paragraph? I think I agree with you that Hagrid is decrying the Malfoys as a group, not purebloods in general. But your logic could be spelled out more. Why exactly is the blood of the Malfoys bad, more so than of other purebloods?

Comment: @Mithrandir - *cough* Blacks *cough* Sirius.

Comment: @Mithrandir and Andromeda...

Comment: I would add to this answer the common English use of "blood" to indicate a familial relationship, esp. in certain idioms like "Blood is thicker than water" to denote the strength of familial ties, "____ runs in our veins" to denote common familial elements, hence Hagrid uses "bad blood" to paint all the Malfoys with a broad brush. This may or may not be intentional on the part of Rowling, but it serves as another emphasis on the importance of blood in the novel.

Comment: @DVK meh, he disowned them, they disowned him :P

Comment: @TheDarkLord "blood" here is a metaphor for family. Hagrid sees Malfoy as coming from a bad family, educated in all the wrong values.

Answer (score 37):

*"...prejudice of this sort is out of character for Hagrid."*

That's... not entirely true.
There are many examples in which Hagrid engages in casual racism, and is shown as prejudiced against some groups, but as he is introduced as a sympathetic character who opposes bad people the reader tends to skip over and justify his behaviour. Just to give a few examples:

Hagrid on centaurs:

> ‘Never,’ said Hagrid irritably, ‘try an’ get a straight answer out of
>   a centaur. Ruddy star-gazers. Not interested in anythin’ closer’n the
>   moon.’ ~Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone: The Forbidden Forest

Hadrid tells this behind the back of a centaur with whom he is in a friendly terms to a group of first years.
Good teacher material, isn't he?

Hagrid on muggles:

> ‘I’d like ter see a great Muggle like you stop him,’ he said. ‘A
>   what?’ said Harry, interested. ‘A Muggle,’ said Hagrid. ‘It’s what we
>   call non-magic folk like them. An’ it’s your bad luck you grew up in a
>   family o’ the biggest Muggles I ever laid eyes on.’ ~Harry Potter and the
>   Philosopher's stone: The Keeper of the Keys

Notice -  not the 'worst people' but 'the biggest Muggles'. As the Dursleys are terrible people who abused a minor who was under their care, the reader feels that Hagrid's behaviour is justified.

Hagrid on house elves:

> “It’d be doin’ ’em an unkindness, Hermione,” said gravely, threading a
>   massive bone needle with thick yellow yarn. “It’s in their nature ter
>   look after humans, that’s what they like, see? Yeh’d be makin’ ’em
>   unhappy ter take away their work, an’ insutin’ ’em if yeh tried ter
>   pay ’em.” “But Harry set Dobby free, and he was over the moon about
>   it!” said Hermione. “And we heard he’s asking for wages now!” “Yeah,
>   well, yeh get weirdos in every breed. I’m not sayin’ there isn’t the
>   odd elf who’d take freedom, but yeh’ll never persuade most of ’em ter
>   do it—no, nothin’ doin’, Hermione.” ~Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire

I am not saying that Hermione's single minded approach is the right one,  far from it. But the issue is more complex than Hagrid's 'they like it'.
Hagrid has his racial stereotypes he's comfortable with, and it will be difficult, if not impossible to convince him otherwise.

On the other hand, one could claim that Hagrid in general uses derogatory language and expressions when he is irritated with someone. Some of those aren't racial slurs:

> Uncle Vernon said sharply, ‘Don’t touch anything he gives you,
>   Dudley.’ The giant chuckled darkly. ‘Yer great puddin’ of a son don’
>   need fattenin’ any more, Dursley, don’  worry.’ ~Harry Potter and the
>   Philosopher's stone: The Keeper of the Keys

Which probably could mean that Hagrid insults people in general when he dislikes them, using his limited vocabulary and insults he is familiar with. As it happens, many insults in the wizarding world tend to be about race and blood,  so that's what we hear from him.

It was probably the case when Hagrid used the 'bad blood' expression - he wanted to say something negative about a family he disliked and pulled out a slur from his vocabulary.

It is ironic, really, that Hagrid uses loaded 'purist' terminology so popular with death eaters to describe the very group/family he disagrees with - but as we know, [Hagrid is not the sharpest tool in the shed](http://e.lvme.me/tqnl5vl.jpg)... and using inappropriate terms by people who oppose the ideology behind those terms happens more often than you would think.

Comment: The question isn't about whether Hagrid was prejudiced in general. It was about his use of 'bad blood' in Flourish and Blotts. Do you think he was being anti-purebloods and if so why?

Comment: @TheDarkLord the  title misled me. Added that bit.

Comment: An alternative view to Hagrid's summary of various magical species is that he's experienced rather than discriminatory, which is feasible if these attributes are true measures of the species.

Comment: @Samthere so we should trust his judgement about slytherins being bad, elves should remain perpetual slaves? And that acromantulas make nice pets?

Comment: @Morri Well, understanding magical creatures and other species is his expertise, so possibly not Slytherins. He might be wrong in saying that the world is better with house elves being servile, but he's correct in summarising the culture of the elves. What he describes is, in general, fairly accurate to how the elves themselves feel. Acromantulas as pets further highlights his expertise in handling other species, to the point that he thinks it trivial and doesn't realise how hard it would be for other people.

Comment: @Morri  I'm not saying he's not flawed, just that there can be a difference between prejudice and experience, based on what reality is. I don't feel that Rowling is exploring the nuance of Hagrid being discriminatory in at least some of these cases, just using him for exposition.

Comment: @Samthere thing is JKR's writing became more nuanced with every book, but Hagrid is the character who stayed the same through all seven and with him stayed those gross generalisations i am so allergic to. Good thing that later Hagrid is used mainly for describing thestrals and those fire-puking worms and not for world expo.

Comment: Concerning your image link ("shouldn't have said that"), I wonder, _was_ that really accidentally or did Hagrid actually act very well, somehow knowing/suspecting/intending what Harry would do with the information spoiled?

Comment: @Zommuter Doubt it. If it was planned, then likely by Dumbledore, giving HP the cloak, thus letting him loose on Hogwarts grounds and counting on that imbecile Hagrid, HP's new friend to leak info.

Comment: I think Hagrid just looks at them and is realistic. You wouldn't call it racial if he said:"Vulcans and their logic".

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen I find jokes about vulcans hilarious, but the only (half) volcan i know has the same rights as other crew members. Were it otherwise i wouldn't find them half as funny. [wizarding society is backwards and needs an ethical engineer :)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathworld)

Comment: @Morri I was just trying to show that Hagrid just speaks his observations. I wouldn't say the wizarding world is perfect though.Do you recommend me reading Deathworld?

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen i liked it. From what i've read so far of Harry Harrison's books (the Deathworld trilogy and a few of the stainless steel rat books) he's really good and deserves our attention.

Comment: @Morri I will put it on the list! Cheers

Answer (score 8):

> Then it struck me that he could mean something else. He could be saying that the Malfoys are inherently spiteful, argumentative or disdainful simply because they are pure-bloods. In other words, he thinks that the 'blood' of the Malfoys makes them what they are.

You forget that the Weasleys are pure blood as well. It is just an English expression.

Comment: What does this add that I haven't already said in my answer or is in the question itself?

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the answers already given

Comment: Jeez, you guys are like dementors.

Comment: @Dr_Bunsen without a sense of humour and hovering? It may seem like that but we're more like prof McGonagall - if you abide by the rules you can have [politicly correct and sensible fun here](https://i.pinimg.com/564x/80/06/75/80067557a4e27851c1a2fca395b79225--harry-potter-cast-goblet-of-fire.jpg)

Comment: I disagree Alith and Mithrandir, this does raise a good point. It is indeed reasonably common amongst the older British generation to refer to families who are known to be "problematic" by the person speaking (for whatever reason, right or wrong) to be referred to as "Bad Blood" - "She's just like her mother. Bad Blood there". It's fallen out of fashion now, probably due to its similarity/closeness to racism and other forms of discrimination.

Comment: @Miller86 sooo... three people agreed with you that it's a good point, but no UV's?

Comment: @Miller86 Note though that Hagrid says that **it is** bad blood, not that **they are** bad blood.

Comment: @Morri That's probably because it's a two-sentence answer.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - it doesn't matter the phrasing - "It is" works with that phrase too :) In this case, "It is" refers literally to their blood as if it's the problem - quite a common variant. "It's just bad blood" is often a way of saying that a whole family is "unsavory" for whatever reason - usually connoting underhanded, criminal or other dodgy behaviors. It's not bringing their "Status" as pure blood into it. The slightly worrying connotations are why its fallen out of fashion.